# Why doesn't the javac compiler flag this code with a warning about varargs ambiguity?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

The following 2 lines of code compile OK.  However, I think it's unuseable, because I can't think of any method invocations that will work with it.

```
// If I can't use this code, why not warn me about it?
void method(int... x) { }
void method(int x, int... y) { }
```

For instance, the following 2 lines of code both cause the javac compiler to issue an error message about varargs ambiguity.

```
// Both invocations fail to compile.
method(1);
method(1,1);
```

I wondered if the javac compiler had its warnings messages disabled by default, and so I tried compiling my code with the javac -Xlint option, but that didn't change things.  Any comments gratefully received.  Thank you.

Comment: Try this: int[] blam = {1}; method(blam); method(1, blam);

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect, other than "because it doesn't have this check."

Comment: the method definitions are not ambiguous.  the method invocations are ambiguous.  try this as well: method(1, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As DwB suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993666/why-doesnt-the-javac-compiler-flag-this-code-with-a-warning-about-varargs-ambig#comment35116669_22993666)

> Try this: `int[] blam = {1}; method(blam); method(1, blam);`

In other words, you can still call the method you want by using values of type `int[]` where a vararg is declared.